# nodetool cfstats Compacted partition maximum bytes

Tags: cassandra

I am worried about the "Compacted partition maximum bytes" value as it seems pretty high with 89MB.

Does this indicate a broken model or some other issue? 
Application side there are no issues observed.

Data stored to the table is packed into weekly buckets for each device using the ***week_first_day, device_id*** partition key.

The data model for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE device_data (
week_first_day timestamp,
device_id uuid,
nano_since_epoch bigint,
sensor_id uuid,
source text,
unit text,
username text,
value double,
PRIMARY KEY ((week_first_day, device_id), nano_since_epoch, sensor_id)
)
```

> nodetool cfstats

```
Table: device_data
            SSTable count: 5
            Space used (live): 447558297
            Space used (total): 447558297
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0
            Off heap memory used (total): 211264
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.2610509614736755
            Number of partitions (estimate): 939
            Memtable cell count: 458
            Memtable data size: 63785
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 0
            Local read count: 0
            Local read latency: NaN ms
            Local write count: 458
            Local write latency: 0.058 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Percent repaired: 99.83
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 2216
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 2176
            Index summary off heap memory used: 672
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 208416
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 43
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 89970660
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 1100241
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
            Dropped Mutations: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the access patterns for data in that partitions - if you're reading the whole partition often, then this could cause the problem, but if you're reading only pieces of it, then it shouldn't be a problem.  You may break up partitions by using the day as bucket, for example.

Look to the talk [Myths of Big Partitions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3mGxgnUiRY) from Cassandra Summit 2 years ago - it has more details on how this is handled in Cassandra 3.x.

Comment: Usually the data is retrieved by time periods. Most often its the current day. Less often the current month. I remember that the magic number for max partition size is 100MB, thats why im asking. Further I wonder why the mean and the max size of the compacted partition is spread that wide (89MB vs 1MB). Why is that happening?

Comment: If most of access happens by the day, they I would recommend to use day as a bucket, and if you'll need data for several days, you can issue several requests in the parallel...

Comment: Regarding partition size - it could be that some devices generate much more data than other, so they get bigger partitions...

Comment: Normally devices have about 15 sensors. Each sends data once a minute. That means there are about 150.000 points per device in a week bucket. That sounded not to large as I was evaluating the design. I will continue monitoring the size and probably switch to day buckets.

Comment: does the `username` the same across all measurements for particular device? If yes, then you can declare it as a static, and it will be the same for all rows in partition...

Comment: username is in 99% of all cases the same but it can be different.